# Count occurance of value over cases

Tags: r, matrix, count

In my dataset, I have 6 Variables with four possible values each (1,10,100 or NA)

```
set.seed(1)
x <- setNames(
  as.data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1,10,100,NA), 10, replace = TRUE))),
  letters[c(1:5,7)])
```

I would like to count how often each value appears per case over all six variables, resulting in three scales (No_of_1s, No_of_10s, No_of_100s) all ranging from 0 to 6.

So far, I used this

```
All<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,g)
All_table<-apply(All,MARGIN=1,table)
```

which gives me the counts of 1s,10s and 100s for each case in a table.

I was thinking now of using

```
No_of_1s<-All_table[,1]
```

to create the variable I need. However, it appears that `All_table` does not create zeros for empty rows but instead just omits them for that case, resulting in a gigantic mess.

Does anyone know how to adjust this?

The solution to this problem is probably pretty straightforward but I can´t seem to figure it out myself.

Comment: please make your question reproducible

Comment: Will do! (Sorry for violating the rules, this is my first post here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```
No_of_10s <- rowSums(All == 10)
No_of_100s <- rowSums(All == 100)
```

I tested this in a data.frame like this:

```
x <- data.frame(a = sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE), b = sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE), c=sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE), d=sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE), e=sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE), g=sample(c(1,10,100), 10, replace = TRUE))
rowSums(x == 10)
# answer
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick answer (I used your example to make my question reproducable btw.)

Works perfectly well for me if I use

`rowSums(x == 10,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Great :-)
Would be awesome if you could accept my answer as a right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would do (thanks to @akrun)...

```
table(id = seq(nrow(x))[row(x)], unlist(x), useNA= "ifany")
```

Or with the reshape2 package

```
library(reshape2)
x$id = seq(nrow(x))
table(melt(x, id="id")[, c("id","value")], useNA="ifany")

    value
id   1 10 100 <NA>
  1  1  3   0    2
  2  2  1   2    1
  3  0  2   3    1
  4  3  1   1    1
  5  2  1   1    2
  6  1  2   1    2
  7  2  1   1    2
  8  1  2   2    1
  9  0  1   4    1
  10 1  3   1    1
```

You might also want to look into the `log10` if your data follows this pattern to higher numbers.

Comment: Thanks!
Using th Log does not really sense for me though since the 1´s 10´s and 100´s are just numerical representations of a factor.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @akrun , added it